# building error in pgs4a - Linux

Tags: android, python, linux

I use Fedora Linux

I installed the pgs4a 0.9.4 and have my sdk updated with the api-8 ok, but when I try to build using "./android.py build /home/armando/projects/games/amh release install > log_building.txt", I get this result from my terminal

```
./android.py build /home/armando/projects/games/amh release install

Updating build files.

Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Added file ./build.xml
Updated file ./proguard-project.txt
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.

Creating assets directory.


Packaging internal data.

Listing private ...
Listing private/lib ...
Listing private/lib/PIL ...
Listing private/lib/android ...
Compiling private/lib/android/__init__.py ...
Compiling private/lib/android/apk.py ...
Compiling private/lib/android/mixer.py ...
Listing private/lib/encodings ...
Listing private/lib/json ...
Listing private/lib/pygame ...
Listing private/lib/pygame/threads ...
Listing private/lib/sqlite3 ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh ...
Compiling /home/armando/projects/games/amh/editor.py ...
Compiling /home/armando/projects/games/amh/game.py ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/levels ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/levels/scores ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/res ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/res/icons ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/res/sfx ...
Listing /home/armando/projects/games/amh/res/tiles ...
Compiling /home/armando/projects/games/amh/run_game.py ...
Compiling /home/armando/projects/games/amh/tile.py ...
Listing engine-private ...

I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: madals_amh
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/gen
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] No Libraries
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: madalenas_mhajong-madalenas
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for madals_amh...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1.2
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for madalenas_mhajong-madalenas...
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /home/armando/projects/pgs4a/bin/AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: Error: Float         types not allowed (at 'versionCode' with value '1.0').

BUILD FAILED
/home/armando/projects/pgs4a/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error     occurred while executing this line:
/home/armando/projects/pgs4a/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 6 seconds

The build seems to have failed.
```

- First: if someone here knows how to solve this error, I would greatly appreciate it if you help me
- Second: anybody in this forum know how I can use a existing sdk installation in my home dierctory with I use to compile programs using processing and it is wroking fine for me at now, it install my apk in my device without any problem also. 
  so, wich file I need to change to apoint to the my "~/sdk" directory, instead of pointing to the "pgs4a/android-sdk" directory, when I command "./android.py build ..." in my shell?

peace!
marquessbr

Posts: 1
Joined: Tue May 20, 2014 11:47 am
Top

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
./android.py configure directory
```

again and use a version number that is an integer.

I have a video of the config process for pgs4a 0.9.4 here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEc72xutmco&feature=share&list=PLxvyAnoL-vu5sNgzos6_v6nX-j8N4H-Pd&index=6

It is running on Ubuntu.  I've installed pgs4a on Linux a number of times and the install and build went smoothly.  Feel free to ask me more questions if you're still stuck.

Oh, I also have a FAQ here:
http://discussion.pychildren.org/t/faq-for-python-on-android-development/9

It was originally intended for kids, but adults seem to be using the FAQ more.

Comment: thak you friend
I have solved it by downloading the new version of pgs4a